# Оборот "к лицу" в значении "подходит"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, стилистика

Насколько корректно выражение: ***это колье, цепочка тебе к лицу***?
Обычно так говорят об одежде, косметике, прическе и подобном: о том, что ближе к лицу или у лица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К ЛИЦУ
**1. что** [*кому*] быть
Подходит; хорошо, отлично.

*Туалет дополняют **несколько нитей ярко-красных кораллов**. Но этот наряд **к лицу** Агнессе. Он оттеняет смуглую кожу, цвет глаз, вьющиеся чёрные волосы, небрежно закрученные на затылке в тяжёлый пучок...* (Ю. Дольд-Михайлик. У Чёрных рыцарей)
[**Фразеологический словарь русского языка**](https://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/983/%D0%9A_%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%A6%D0%A3)

*В самом деле, охотничий костюм был ей изумительно **к лицу**: на ней была фетровая шляпа с голубыми перьями, бархатный лиф жемчужно-серого цвета **с алмазными застежками** и юбка из голубого атласа, вся расшитая серебром.*
[А. Дюма. Три мушкетёра](http://book-online.com.ua/read.php?book=2124&page=100)

*— Тебе очень **к лицу бриллианты*** [великолепное колье из сапфиров и бриллиантов и длинные серьги].
Р. Ли. Мой любимый враг

*Странно, но ей — крупной, большой, неуклюжей — **бусы, висюльки и браслеты были к лицу*** (из статьи).

"Женщина, ***одетая к лицу*,** — это привлекательная женщина; она вызывает положительное эстетическое восприятие и интерес со стороны окружающих. *Гармония во внешнем виде женщины является залогом её успеха* (*курсив* — мой)".

Мне кажется, что вполне корректно говорить про украшения (брошь, серьги, подвеска, браслет, колье...) — к лицу. Аксессуары — это лишь одни из частичек, создающих гармонию.

Answer (score 1):

Грамота дала исчерпываюший [ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=293158).

*Вопрос № 293158

Можно ли сказать: "Эта юбка (брюки) тебе к лицу"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Это очень интересный вопрос: можно ли сказать об одежде, которая надевается, так сказать, ниже талии (например, брюках, шортах, юбке), что она к лицу? В словарях этот оборот толкуется довольно широко: «подходит, идет кому-либо», «делает привлекательным кого-либо (о костюме, прическе)», «идет кому-нибудь, вполне гармонирует с чем-нибудь». Однако он употребляется активно именно по отношению к тому, что расположено ближе к лицу человека – платью, блузке, прическе, шляпке. И хотя слово лицо может использоваться метонимически – в значении внешний облик, но обороты «туфли вам к лицу», «цвет чулок вам очень к лицу» звучат комично, потому что в них происходит буквализация оборота. Юбки и брюки оказываются как бы на грани допустимого. В «Большом фразеологическом словаре русского языка» В. Н. Телии (М., 2006) приводится такой интересный пример: Она стояла на пороге своей комнаты, смотрела настороженно, но улыбку изобразила. Молода, стройна, длиннонога, светлые волосы распущены по плечам. Синие джинсы и голубой свитер ей явно к лицу, если бы не складка на переносице и тонко поджатые губы, я назвал бы ее хорошенькой (Огонек, 1997). Здесь к лицу оказываются джинсы, но не одни, а со свитером – опять как единое целое, костюм.
Подведем итог: про одежду ниже пояса лучше говорить – идет, подходит. А оборот к лицу в том же значении можно смело использовать по отношению к пальто, костюму, джемперу, панаме, палантину, фате, макияжу, бороде – то есть к тому, что оказывается именно у лица или на лице.*

---

Применив этот подход к колье и цепочкам, о которых говорилось в вопросе, легко прийти к выводу, что можно смело использовать оборот "тебе к лицу" по отношению к ним.

Comment: Это я читала, только там нет ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: Мой вопрос именно о цепочке.колье.

Comment: Наталья, я дополнил мой ответ.